# Python List - Return Index

Tags: python, list, duplicates, list-comprehension

For the list below - "A" - I would like to return the index of the elements in "A".....except if the element in "A" equals 'SCR'. Given this list/ code:

INPUT:

```
A=['126.00', '9.00', '1.50', '9.50', '9.50', 'SCR', '19.00', '12.00']
B=[(A.index(i)+1) for i in A if not i=='SCR']
print(B)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 7, 8]
```

Notice that 4 repeats.

The required output is:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,7,8]
```

Comment: `B = [index for item, index in enumerate(A) if item != "SCR"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `list.index()`, it returns the **first match**. So when i='9.50' you get the index of its first occurrence.

To avoid that, you can do something like this:

```
A=['126.00', '9.00', '1.50', '9.50', '9.50', 'SCR', '19.00', '12.00']
B=[i+1 for i in range(len(A)) if not A[i]=='SCR']
print(B)

>>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get the indices as you loop over the list:

```
A=['126.00', '9.00', '1.50', '9.50', '9.50', 'SCR', '19.00', '12.00']
B=[i for i, v in enumerate(A, 1) if v!='SCR']
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8]
```

Comment: Agreed @AndrejKesely, that is nicer.

Comment: Thanks - I'll brush up on 'enumerate'

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
b=[]
for i in range(len(A)):
    if A[i] != "SCR":
        b.append(i+1)

print (b)
```

Explanation:

- If we just need to print the index number, we can get it via "for i in range(len(A))". Here, it's value will be: 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
- With if A[i] != "SCR", we are checking if value of that index is equals to SCR, if not, then add that index value to another array - B

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah it will repeat because python starts checking from the front one by one and as soon as it finds one it stops.

To get rid of this problem just delete the element at that index when found.

Also you can just do one thing--

A=['126.00', '9.00', '1.50', '9.50', '9.50', 'SCR', '19.00', '12.00']
B=[(i+1) for i in A if not i=='SCR']
print(B)